# Find and Replace within a SINGLES CELL, when using VScode with Jupyter

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, jupyter

When using VScode and its Jupyter notebook extension, is there a way to replace matched characters within a single cell? say I want to replace all "temp_" with "" within a single cell; when I use ctrl+F to search and replace, it always search through the entire notebook.

Comment: what if you select the cell's code and use **Find/Replace in Selection** one of the buttons in the Find dialog

Comment: @rioV8 Tried that, doesnt seem to work.. does it work for you?